# Selenium Freezing on large pages

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping a very large document, and when I call:

```
 page_source = driver.page_source
```

It freezes and isn't able to capture the full page source.  Is there something I can do to mitigate this issue?  The page is from an autoscroll and I can't access to the source.

Comment: Can you share the link to the target page? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround it with an [`execute_script()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

```
driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
```

You can also try scrolling into view of the footer and only then get the page source:

```
footer = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("footer")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer)

print(driver.page_source)
```

Assuming there is the `footer` element, of course.

Comment: wouldn't this only return the footer's source?

Comment: @Rob nope, `driver.page_source` would return the complete page source. My bet here is that scrolling to the footer would help to "complete" the page source. This is a guess, of course, at this moment. Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is it's massive, it's like tens of thousands of autoscrolls in a row

Comment: @Rob okay, did you have any success with `execute_script()` approach? Thanks.